# Schedule event with alarm manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I would like to program an event (it will be a notification) 30 minutes later.
To develop I use 10 seconds later.
Here is my code

```
val myFlags = when {
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S ->
                PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
            else -> {
                PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
            }
        }
        val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager?
        val myAlarmIntent = Intent(context, MyAlarmReceiver::class.java)
        val myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            42,
            myAlarmIntent,
            myFlags
        )
        val repeatingCalendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
            add(Calendar.SECOND,
                10)
        }
        Log.d("***Alarm set***",repeatingCalendar.time.toString())
        manager!!.setExact(
            AlarmManager.RTC,
            repeatingCalendar.timeInMillis,
            myPendingIntent
        )

class MyAlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Log.d("***MyAlarmReceiver***", "onReceive")
    }
}
```

Alarm is never received. By the way I have both permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you add a `<receiver>` element to the manifest for `MyAlarmReceiver`?